# Nuxt/Vue-meta: info.meta.filter is not a function

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-meta

I am working on a website that runs Nuxt in Universal Mode. Together with another developer we have been working on it for a few month now. We use Git to collaborate on different branches, which we then integrate at certain moments when we are releasing a new version of the website.

Since yesterday we are running into something we cannot explain properly. Whenever I try to run `nuxt`, `nuxt generate`, `npm install <package-name>` the application crashes with the same error:

[image]

We suspect it might has to do with a recent **Babel/Webpack** upgrade in our `package.json`, since the errors we get also mention some `core-js` errors. The strange thing about all of this, is that when we revert back to an old commit, the application still crashes with exactly the same error. Only after we delete the repository locally and clone it again and install all of our dependencies with `npm install`, we are able to revert back to that same commit and get the website up and running again.

Some other information from our `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "dev": "HOST=0.0.0.0 nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "gsap": "^3.0.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.10.2",
    "swiper": "^5.2.1",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^1.1.2",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.15.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1"
  },
  "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "host": "188.166.41.47",
      "port": "3000"
    }
  }
```

After deleting the `package-lock.json`, `node_modules` folder and `.nuxt` folder we tried running `npm install` again. This resulted in a successful installation, albeit with one error:

***npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.***

This however, is not something we have explicitly registered in our package.json..

Comment: Are you pushing and merging your package-lock file?

Comment: I think that that happened once, accidentally. Aren't we supposed to push this file?

Comment: You should push this file, to always have the same versions on different setups where the code is compiled.

Answer (score 5):

Fix  - change the meta to be an array of objects. See bellow explanation.

I have encountered myself this problem and I found an easy fix. filter() is an built in method for the array constructor. That means that the object that we call the method on is not an array.

My code looked like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>                    
            <h1>Events</h1>          
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    head(){
        return {
            title: 'Sergiu Mare - Home page',
            meta: {
                hid: 'description',
                name: 'description',
                content: 'All the information that are about the freelancer Sergiu Mare.'
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and I changed it to

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>                    
            <h1>Events</h1>          
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    head(){
        return {
            title: 'Sergiu MAre - Home page',
            meta: [
                {hid: 'description'},
                {name: 'description'},
                {content: 'All the information that are about the freelancer Sergiu Mare.'}
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and now if I inspect the page the meta information is there.

[image]

Comment: solved for me changing meta from dict to array

Answer (score 0):

Since you've now overcome the first issue because of the `package-lock.json` file.

The second should be resolved by updating your dependencies if it's not breaking anything, it might be `nuxt` which is using the core-js, so you can try upgrading that dependency to the latest (2.11.0), otherwise it's just upgrading one by one if you want the warning to disappear (it's just a warn, so you can actually leave it our for now)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but if there are core-js erros

```
yarn add --dev core-js@2 @babel/runtime-corejs2

npm install core-js@2 @babel/runtime-corejs2
```

could help

Answer (score 0):

The highest rated answer is on the right track, but it's not correct.
it should be written as an array of objects like this

```html
<script>
export default {
head() {
    return {
      title: "Sergiu MAre - Home page",
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: "All the information that are about the freelancer Sergiu Mare.",
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

and from the docs

> To avoid any duplication when used in child components, please give a unique identifier with the `hid` key to the meta description. This way `vue-meta` will know that it has to overwrite the default tag.

source: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/